# Sort a List<object> by two properties one in ascending and the other in descending order in dart

Tags: sorting, flutter, dart

I saw examples where I can sort a list in dart using one property in flutter(dart).

But how can I do the functionality which an SQL query does like for example:
order by points desc, time asc

Comment: `List.sort()` method takes optional `compare` function - use it for comparing the items - but you can also implement `Comparable` in your data class

Comment: When i just use List.sort, i was able to sort it with one property alone. Implementing comparable did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list then sort it again..

Here is a sample I made from dartpad.dev

```
void main() {

  Object x = Object(name: 'Helloabc', i: 1);
  Object y = Object(name: 'Othello', i: 3);
  Object z = Object(name: 'Avatar', i: 2);

  List<Object> _objects = [
      x, y, z
  ];

 _objects.sort((a, b) => a.name.length.compareTo(b.name.length));

/// second sorting
//   _objects.sort((a, b) => a.i.compareTo(b.i));

  for (Object a in _objects) {
    print(a.name);
  }
}

class Object {
  final String name;
  final int i;

  Object({this.name, this.i});
}
```

Comment: `List.sort` is *not* a stable sort, so the second sort should not be expected to preserve ordering from the first sort.  For a stable sort, you instead should use something like [`mergeSort`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/mergeSort.html) from [`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/mergeSort.html).

Comment: @Pol ,I have tried using sort again on a sorted list. When I do so I lose the first sort.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer for this. Thanks to @pskink and the url
https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-sorting-list-with-comparator-and-comparable.

I implemented the Comparable to sort by the two properties.

```
    class Sample implements Comparable<Sample> {
  final int points;
  final int timeInSeconds;
  Sample(
      {
      this.points,
      this.timeInSeconds});

  @override
  int compareTo(Sample other) {
    int pointDifference = points- other.points;
    return pointDifference != 0
        ? pointDifference 
        : other.timeInSeconds.compareTo(this.timeInSeconds);
  }
}

sampleList.sort();
```